# Given a set of integers, and a length n - can we find the minimum difference between any two sums of combinations of size n?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

Actually my question is slightly tougher than the title.

Say we have n sets of n integers of varying size.
We make combinations of integers, one and only one integer from each set.  So, each combination is of size n.

Is it reasonably possible to calculate the minimum possible difference in the sums of any two combinations, given a finite "n" and finite range on the size of integers?

Comment: This has the combinatoric feel of NP-hard problems to me.  If the range is small enough you can prove that there must be sets with equal sum.  There are $n^n$ possible combinations so if the range in each set is less than $n^{n-1}$ there must be two that have the same sum.

Comment: What is your definition of "reasonably possible?"